# Java How to call a method from another mock method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Is it possible to call some method from another mock method instead of returning a value using Mockito or PowerMock ?

Here is example to make in clear:

I have a query in production class:

```
session.createQuery("update clause")
                    .setParameter("")
                    .executeUpdate();
session.flush();
```

And in my test class I mock it this way:

```
Query q = mock(Query.class, "q");
when(session.createQuery("update lalala")).thenReturn(q);
when(q.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(something);
```

Now instead of doing `thenReturn(something)` I need to call a void method that's situated in my test class too that mocks database behaviour.

i.e.

```
public void doSomething()
{
  // do smth
}
```

So that in my test when q.executeUpdate is called then doSomething() is then called too.

I googled for any possible ideas but just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `thenAnswer` function. See the [documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer))

```
when(q.executeUpdate()).thenAnswer( new Answer<Foo>() {
    @Override
    public Foo answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
      callYourOtherMethodHere();
      return something;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! I tried messing with custom Answers yesterday but seems I was doing it wrong.

Comment: This won't work in the case Alexandra is asking about.  She specifically said she needed to stub a void method, but this only works for non-void methods.  You need to use the `doAnswer` syntax to set up your answer.  Fortunately, the link that you provided is the link to the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with EasyMock (maybe with other mocking tools too).

```
Query q = createMock(Query.class)
expect(q.createQuery("update lalala")).andDelegateTo(anObjectThatCalls_doSomething);
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use EasyMock in this project but only Mockito or PowerMock